# Tab Controller freezes and phone gets laggy after [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url];

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios7

As soon as this line happens, I can no longer use the tab controller, and the phone I'm testing on becomes very laggy.

```
    NSString *webData= [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Any idea why that would happen?

url is:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
```

Comment: I would say you are probably loading a very large string.

Comment: Well it is the source HTML of a we page...

Comment: I could see how that would cause some lag, but why would it stop my tab bar from working?

Comment: Well if it's HTML source of a large web page, then that explains it. Loading very large amount of memory will block your main thread. You can try doing this in the background thread.

Comment: It's not a huge site, just has a text list of times on it.

Comment: Log `[webData length]` to be sure. Plus, if you don't have a great connectivity, it'd take more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `stringWithContentsOfURL:` is a blocking call. If you're going to use that method, you should call it on a background thread. When you call it on the main thread, you won't be able to interact with your app until it finishes downloading the string.

Basically, when you call `stringWithContentsOfURL:`, the thread that that is called on won't be able to do anything else until the call finishes. If you're calling it from the UI thread, this means that your app won't be able to respond to, for example, touch events. If you put this on a background thread, or add more sophisticated non-blocking networking, you won't have that problem.

It is also deprecated as of iOS 7; it's recommended that you use `stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was pulling a small HTML constantly, which was making things freeze and lag.

I wrapped some conditionals around it so it only pulls the HTML when I really need it to, and everything sped back up.